# In Cortex M3 microcontroller, When will variables in .data section of Flash are copied to SRAM,Is

Tags: cortex-m, keil, nxp-microcontroller

In Cortex M3 micro controller, When will variables in .data section of Flash are copied to SRAM,Is it before fetching of reset and initial SP pointers or later? Am using Keil4 and LPC 1778.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it normally goes:

1. MCU's bootloader does minimum HW init, reads SP and PC from FLASH, and starts user code;
2. User code copies `.data` from FLASH to RAM and zeroes `.bss`;
3. main() is called.

For example:

- Reset handler: http://repo.or.cz/cbaos.git/blob/HEAD:/arch/arm-cortex-m3/crt.c
- `.data` and `.bss` init :http://repo.or.cz/cbaos.git/blob/HEAD:/kernel/init.c

Comment: Can you show me where in keil start up file is this happening [link](https://github.com/openxc/nxp-cdl/blob/master/CMSISv2p00_LPC177x_8x/src/startup_LPC177x_8x.s)

Comment: Sorry, the linked files are for bare system. Looks for files like `crt` in Keil. (crt means C runtime) They should include this code.

Answer (score 0):

In the reset handler, .S file we can check the code how the flow is there.
In the initialization, before assigning SP, data will be copied